# Não consigo retornar outro campo a não ser a chave primária usando o $project

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, json, mongodb, nosql

Estou iniciando em MongoDB e gostaria de realizar uma consulta no meu banco do tipo: Quais animais ficaram doentes no ano de 2016?

Usando o $group e o $project:

```
db.animais.aggregate([
{$unwind : "$doencas" },
{$project : {
     year : {$year : "$doencas.data_diagnostico"}
}},
{$match : {year :{$eq: 2016}}},
{$group:{
    _id:'$_id'}
}
])
```

Sáida:

```
{ "_id" : "014" }
{ "_id" : "001" }
```

Porém se eu trocar '$_id' por '$apelido':

```
db.animais.aggregate([
{$unwind : "$doencas" },
{$match : {"doencas.data_diagnostico":{$gt: new Date(2015,11,31)}}},
{$match : {"doencas.data_diagnostico":{$lt: new Date(2017,01,01)}}},
{$group:{
    _id:'$apelido'}
}
])
```

O retorno é  `{ "_id" : null }`.

A única forma que encontrei de fazer retornando o apelido é não usar $project, por exemplo:

```
db.animais.aggregate([
{$unwind : "$doencas" },
{$match : {"doencas.data_diagnostico":{$gt: new Date(2015,11,31)}}},
{$match : {"doencas.data_diagnostico":{$lt: new Date(2017,01,01)}}},
{$group:{
    _id:'$apelido'}
}
])
```

Saída:

```
{ "_id" : "Golias" }
{ "_id" : "Zoe" }
```

Alguém sabe como retornar o campo 'apelido' fazendo uso do $project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gente consegui, era só projetar o atributo que queria mostrar.

```
db.animais.aggregate([
{$unwind : "$doencas" },
{$project : {
    year : {$year : "$doencas.data_diagnostico"},
    apelido: 1
}},
{$match : {year :{$eq: 2016}}},
{$group:{
   _id:'$apelido'}
}
])
```